# How to query a component by component name that contain some part of string

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query()` to query name of button that contain some path of name.

**Assume I have 4 button with name declare as 'edit_btn', 'add_btn', 'add2_btn' and 'edit2_btn'**

Then I use query.
`Ext.ComponentQuery.query("button[name='*edit*']");`

I should get **''edit_btn'**' and **''edit2_btn'**' button.

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query("button[name='*add*']");`

I should get **''add_btn'**' and **'add2_btn'** button.

Or I can use regex in `Ext.ComponentQuery.query()` command?

If can, How to use it?

Comment: i don't know if you can use regex in Component query, but you should take in consideration simpler solutions, like adding an extra config: buttonType: 'edit' or 'Add' and then query for "button[buttonType=edit]"

Comment: hmm I think about that solution too. But the problem is [Netzke gem](https://github.com/skozlov/netzke-basepack).
It auto generate component name (a bad name eg. panel__admin_grid__adminform up to your stack of component level).
If I gave it a name for each component that is a such of pain for me.
Anyway, Thank for your idea @nscrob :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not implemented. I looked at the source code, and there is only equality operator implemented. Hovewer it's easy to extend it (see `filterByAttribute` in ComponentQuery.html file), but you must copy all the code from source, because it's implemented as singleton.

Another way is to select buttons which have name attribute and filter later, eg:

```
Ext.Array.filter(
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[name]'), 
    function(c){ return /^add/.test(c.name); }
)
```