# Ext Component Query Selector formats & options

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am a novice in Sencha Touch 2 & Ext too. I have jquery knowledge, so I am relating few things similar for quick understanding but got stuck in selector query.

I am creating dynamic textfields like:

```
var autoSuggestField = 'people_' + counter;  // suppose counter is looping 5 times
var field =  new Ext.field.Text({
        name: autoSuggestField,
        itemId: 'testing',                   // just for testing
        // itemId: autoSuggestField,         // actual code
        inputCls:'auto-suggest',
        placeHolder:'Select People',
        cls:'place-holder',
        listeners: {
            clearicontap:function(obj, e, eOpts) {
                // tried option 1
                var allPeople = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.place-holder .auto-suggest');
                console.log(allPeople);           // console says '[]'

                // tried option 2
                var allPeople = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.place-holder');
                console.log(allPeople);           // console says '[]'

                // tried option 3
                var allPeople = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.auto-suggest');
                console.log(allPeople);           // console says '[]'

                // tried option 4
                var allPeople = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#testing');
                console.log(allPeople);           // console says '[class , class, class]'
            }
        }
    });
```

But I am looking for something:

```
// var allPeople = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name^=people_]');    // as we do jquery
```

Or anything similar to it, which should work. Please clear what I am doing wrong in option[1,2,3] as most of the post says that using id[option 4] is bad. An how can we achieve using [name^=] "which says any element starting with people_". Is it possible in Ext? Is it possible through REGEX?(just for an idea)

Please add explanations for better understanding of selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for regular expressinons you can add a an extra config like type:'people' for all the people related textfiled components and you can query it using the

```
 var allPeopleComponents = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[type=people]');
```

The above will return the array of components having `type='people'`.

Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615240/how-to-query-a-component-by-component-name-that-contain-some-part-of-string) and for better understanding of ComponentQuery options [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?197145-Can-anyone-here-explain-Ext.ComponentQuery.query(-what-here-comes-)-0-briefly)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot, still I am stuck why Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield') showing 'xtype:hiddenfield' in result set, but when I passed hiddenfield its showing only hiddenfield? Any idea?

Comment: @AakashSahai try to refine your query.What exactly you want ?